# Laravel url() function returns public two times

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel url() function to get website base url, but it returns public two times I don't know where I am doing wrong? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is my code.

```
 <link rel='stylesheet'
        href='{{ url('/') }}/js/background-check.min.js' type='text/css'
        media='all' />
```

Here is the output I get:
https://www.example.com/public/public/js/background-check.min.js

It should look like this:
https://www.example.com/public/js/background-check.min.js

Comment: What is the value of `SITE_URL` in `.env`?

Comment: APP_URL=https://www.example.com

Comment: You tried without the url() ? If you use Laravel mix maybe check this doc: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mix#vendor-extraction
try to use `href="/js/background-check.min.js"` instead?

Comment: Also if you want to include JS use `<script>` tag like this: `<script src="/js/background-check.min.js"></script>`

Comment: then it will return example.com I want public also

Answer (score 0):

you need to not include `public` folder in the url , to do that
if you are using `Apache`
create `.htaccess` file in your root like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

if you are using `Nginx` you can look at the following Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    

    root /var/www/html/quickstart/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

}
```